# Shifting of current sources

Tags: network

[image]

Can someone justify shifting current sources iam not able to understand how it is done

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is one in a series of questions asked without an attempt at a solution.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For me, because of the two different approaches (both worth reading) to "seeing" an answer to this question, I am glad the question was asked. Everyone is getting an +1 from me. It's a weird question (which in this case is good because it got some nice answers.) I'm most attracted to the approach by sarthak because it's based upon a very general observation about current sources and the fact that a shared node between them has infinite impedance to everywhere in the circuit (by definition) and so can be attached to other nodes. It's a useful idea to keep in a back pocket.

Answer (score 4):

I think it can be more easily explained through the following transformations:
[image]

The following is the thought process:

1. A single current source can be converted to two independent sources
   in series.
2. The node between two current sources in series can be
       attached to any other node without violating KCL and KVL.

The dashed red line represent the new connection I am making. With little rearrangement you get your circuit.

Comment: Awesome approach

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. I have a degree in electrical engineering and have worked in the industry for quite a few years, and this is the first time I've ever seen that concept. I've never been taught it and honestly I'm not quite sure why it would be useful, but it does make for an interesting thought exercise :)

Redrawing your circuit, with some more annotation added:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxKdsj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*(By the way, why do they have R1, R2, R2, R3? It could have just as easily been R1, R2, R3, R4...)*

Apply Kirchoff's Current Law to the circuit on the left:
$$I_a+I-I_b=0$$
$$I_b=I_a+I$$
$$I_d-I_a-I=0$$
$$I_d=I_a+I$$
$$I_b-I_c=0$$
$$I_b=I_c$$
$$I_c-I_d=0$$
$$I_c=I_d$$

Now apply Kirchoff's Current Law to the circuit on the right, and we end up with the same results:
$$I_a+I-I_b=0$$
$$I_b=I_a+I$$
$$I_d-I_a-I=0$$
$$I_d=I_a+I$$
$$I_b-I+I-I_c=0$$
$$I_b=I_c$$
$$I_c-I+I-I_d=0$$
$$I_c=I_d$$

That's all just a fancy way of saying "the three new current sources all cancel each other out on the right-hand side, and have the same net effect on the left-hand side of the circuit".

**EDIT / ADDITION**

So @sarthak had a really nice intuitive approach to solving this one. Then @carloc chimed in and asked "what about its dual" (i.e. voltage source instead of a current source, and the other resistors in parallel rather than in series). It turns out I just couldn't get this out of my head! It turns out that yes there is dual case like this, which can be derived using an approach very similar to the one used by @sarthak above:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGMgLH.png)</sup>

I've worked this out and proven to my own satisfaction that yes this works, but the derivation is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: Why you took Ia, ib before and after flowing through resistor. Will there be any change in current after flowing through resistor

Comment: No, Ia and Ib are exactly the same. I was trying to be strictly correct about Kirchoff's Current Law, but now that I think about it my schematic is too complicated, which I find a little embarrassing. I will edit.

Comment: Very interesting, what about its dual.... One voltage generator series with your R2 and several parallel branches downstream....

Comment: @carloc Not sure. I just approached this from first principles, and I find sarthak's answer above to be more intuitive than my own. I know one possible answer to your question is "just use a Norton equivalent circuit to transform it back into a current source with R2 in parallel", but that is undoubtedly weaseling out of your real question. ;-)

Comment: @carloc you really planted an idea into my brain! Yes there is a dual case as you suggest, and I've added it to my answer above.

Comment: Great Mr.Snrub, just what I had in my mind! Well done!